How to get the user's transaction without the tx hash?
As a Dapp developer there are times that the wallet provider that I use, has some bugs and does not return a tx hash to my app for a transaction. in this situation I am not sure if the transaction has been broadcasted or not.
how can I check if the transaction is broadcasted or not without having the tx hash?

Calculate the hash yourself from the signed raw transaction.
>>> tx = {  
  'from': eoa.address, 'to': eoa.address, 'value': 0, 'chainId': w3.eth.chain_id, 'gas': 500000, 
  'gasPrice': w3.eth.gas_price * 2, 'nonce': w3.eth.get_transaction_count(eoa.address) 
}
>>> signed_tx = w3.eth.account.sign_transaction(tx, private_key=eoa.key)
>>> tx_hash = w3.to_hex(w3.keccak(signed_tx.raw_transaction))
>>> tx_hash
'0x4b8802bf83edf75b2ec7dffa2b8cf7b65c86feef5fba77e80a1b9501ecf39f4b'
>>>
>>> receipt = w3.eth.wait_for_transaction_receipt(tx_hash)

Other options could be to monitor all transactions in the surrounding blocks for identifiable values to find yours. Or to poll some 3rd party api that will scrape the data for you.

thank you, couple problems here. first, that we don't have the user's private key ofcourse. second is that if I ask the wallet provider to sign the transaction again, the nonce would be different (or not, but we don't know).

What do you have? How about the alternatives, scan the txpool for transactions from the users address. Or using an explorers api who will do that for you.
